# Installing Oracle Linux 8

Tags: system-installation, oracle-linux

I have built a virtual machines, the CPU has 1 socket with 4 cores and 4GB memory and it has 3 Disks.

I choose the custom storage method as I want to install OL8 assigning the following:

```
/root (/) LVM to sda (25GB)

/boot partition to sdb (5GB)

SWAP LVM to sdc (5GB)
```

After going through custom setup there is no error prompts at all, it get through to the system reboot prompt, when the server restarts all I see is blinking cursor.

Comment: this is most probably related to the VM configuration rather than OL installation itself and then that should be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

Install OL8 with boot mode set to EFI.